# Javascript get every second slide with modulus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, modulus

I have a function that fires every time a slide is advanced in my slideshow, and increments a counter.

I want a simple way to call a function every X slide (5 in the example code).  I realize I can do this easily using modulus but the syntax escapes me.

```
 var numSlides = $('.item').length; // 20
 var currSlide = 0;
 var ad_interval = 5;

 function updateSlide (){ 
    currSlide++
    // if we are at the ad interval, every 5 slides, call the next line
     $("#adslot").reveal();

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mod returns the remainder... When it's 0, you've hit a count on the interval.

```
if((currSlide % ad_interval) === 0) {
   $('#adslot').reveal();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (currSlide % ad_interval === 0) {
    // Note that this will also include the first (0th) slide.
}
```

Comment: Not if it goes after currSlide++;, which is where the asker has the current statement

Answer (score 1):

Inside your updateSlide() method, you can include something like :

```
if(currSlide % ad_interval === 0)
{
     // Run method code.
}
```

This will run a method every 5 slides. For more information on Java operators and the modulus operator, [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) does a pretty good job of explaining them.

Answer (score 1):

Re you looking for this?

```
if (currSlide%5 ==0) {
  $("#adslot").reveal();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function updateSlide (){
    // if we are at the ad interval, every 5 slides, call the next line
    if ((currSlide + 1) % ad_interval == 0){
        $("#adslot").reveal();
    }
    currslide++;
}
```

The reason I'm using `(currSlide + 1) % ad_interval` is simply because your index is zero-based, and the fifth slide would be at index `4`, rather than `5`; the `+1` simply ensures that the the modulus will be `0` *at* the fifth slide, rather than the sixth.

This will also prevent the first, zeroth, slide from showing the ad.

Comment: Leaving the currSlide++; statement at the beginning of the method serves the same function of not showing the ad until the 5th slide, while keeping the code less verbose/confusing.